# why original is not distributed to one data node?

Tags: elasticsearch

i made a elasticsearch cluster.
cluster setting is here.
server1 - master node, data node1
server2 - data node2, data node3

I want the original data to be distributed evenly across all data nodes.
But the original data is stored only in two data nodes(data node1, data node2).
Data node 3 only stores a copy. Why?????
How do I spread the original data evenly?

here is my cluster....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In9Qp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're probably using the [elasticsearch defaults](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html), which means 5 shards and 1 replica per index.

You can have more control over the distribution of your shards and replicas using [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html) and [cluster level sharding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html), specially tuning [shard balancing heuristics.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html#_shard_balancing_heuristics)